# How to make list in one line in css

Tags: css, wordpress

I put into the theme custom widget and I need make list in one line, how can I do it? I tried everything

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Kindly add your code.

Comment: Your question is simple to be replayed but you can simply search on google, anyway you must add a code snippet to your question so that we don't have to recreate all the code, and you can't publish your website link, you may find usefull reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display).

```
#menu-cz-odkazy li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

For some space between the items, give the `li` a `margin-right` of 5px for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
#menu-cz-odkazy li {display: inline-block;}
```

add in your css

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make your `ul` a flexbox

```css
#menu-cz-odkazy {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu-cz-odkazy-container">
  <ul id="menu-cz-odkazy" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1555" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1555"><a href="https://www.propiska-reklamni.cz/">propiska-reklamni.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1556" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1556"><a href="https://www.reklamni-cukrovinky.cz/">reklamni-cukrovinky.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1557" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1557"><a href="https://www.reklamnidary.cz/">www.reklamnidary.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1558" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1558"><a href="http://www.usbdary.cz/">usbdary.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1559" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1559"><a href="https://www.papirovedary.cz/">papirovedary.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1560" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1560"><a href="http://www.expresdary.cz/">expresdary.cz</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1561" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-1561"><a href="https://www.textil-pro-firmy.cz/">textil-pro-firmy.cz</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```